# Eval() Function using ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, eval

Hu everyOne My simple question is :

Is there an equivalent function in `ASP` which does the same as `PHP'`s `EVAL()` function?
I wana do like thsis for example:

```
int result = Eval("2+2");
```

Comment: Luckily, no. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Look i have a Form Collection contains  many properties and values fom Example : FormCollection form; i wanna generate new object{propertie1=value1,propertie2=value2} from the FormCollecion Sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: Please update the question to include exactly what you are doing - there are much better alternatives than `Eval`. MVC has an *awesome* component that parses the Request and creates your objects for you (Model Binder). Even without that, many methods take a `RouteValueDictionary`, so you don't always need an object.

Comment: Please could you tell me how to Use IDictionary to create a new "object" width many properties ?!

Comment: seeing how `eval()` is considered to be an **extremely** bad practice in PHP, why would you ever want to use it in C# (which, admittedly, is a better designed language) ?!